# how to make def main print list after it goes through multiple subroutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, program-entry-point

[image: Python file]

I created a program in which it ask the calories of each cupcake then the program will sort them from highest value to lowest. However when i use def(main) it wouldnt print any value. How to fix the issue, beforehand i didnt the def cal function and it worked.

Comment: You defined a `main()` function, but never called it.

Comment: Please add your code as code-formatted text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

In python there is no special `main()` function that is automatically called when the program starts, like C, java, etc. The `main()` function you wrote is just a normal function. If you don't call it, it won't get called.

Instead, the python equivalent to other langueges' `main()` is

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    print('hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

@blue_note answer should solve your issue and is most accurate.
Well, if you want to execute the main in the same fashion you have defined you can try running the script like this and explicitly calling your main function from the command line. But still, the previous approach should be the preferred one.

`python -c 'from your_python_file import main; main()'`